# phpmailer connection refused

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am not able to send email using PHPMailer. I am running MAMP(localhost:8888) on OSX(yosemite). I followed [this][1] tutorial to set composer globally for MAMP's version of php.

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
alias phpmamp='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.34/bin/php'
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | phpmamp
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
composer
```

Then I have created a **phpmailer** directory in **/Applications/MAMP/htdocs**

*Composer.json:*

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Then in phpmailer directory i typed a command composer install. It downloaded files and I created a file index.php in phpmailer directory.

After grabbing dependencies from git the file structure looks like this:

```
  phpmailer
     |
     |----composer.json 
     |----vendor(directory with various subdirectories and files) 
     |----index.php
     |----composer.lock
```

*Debug Logs:*

```
2015-09-12 19:03:47 Connection: opening to ssl://localhost:25, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2015-09-12 19:03:47   SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (61) 2015-09-12 19:03:47    SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting bool(false)
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

*Code:*

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$m = new PHPMailer;
$m->SMTPDebug = 3;

$m = new PHPMailer;
$m->isSMTP();
$m->SMTPAuth = true;
$m->SMTPDebug = 2;
$m->HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$m->Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$m->Password = 'hidden';
$m->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$m->PORT = 465;
$m->From = "myemail@gmail.com";
$m->FromName = "Android Plus Ios";
$m->addReplyTo('friend@gmail.com','Reply address');
$m->addAddress('friend@mdurohtak.ac.in','Rakesh');
$m->addCC('Jettu@hotmail.com', 'Jitesh');
$m->addBCC('Fudu@outlook.com', 'Fruity');
$m->Subject = "Please verify the account.";
$m->Body = 'Please click here to verify the account registration';
$m->AltBody = 'By Google';
var_dump($m->send());
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is [case sensitive](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php). You should therefore change the following two calls:

```
$m->HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$m->PORT = 465;
```

to

```
$m->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$m->Port = 465;
```